# Java bytecode decompiler in IntelliJIDEA for Scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, jvm-bytecode

I'm using IntellijIDEA Ultimate Edition. Browsing `.class` files that compiled from `java` source code is easy: I can just double-click on `.class` file and IDEA will decompile it.

However, with `.class` files that were compiled from `scala` source code it's not working. It seems that IDEA just referencing to the `scala` source file.

I've noticed that IDEA behaves like that only with `scala plugin` installed. It works fine without it. Is there a way to decompile using IDEA without switching off `scala plugin`?

Comment: Please follow the related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-9913

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it's not implemented yet

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally this feature was released in Intellij.

From [official website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-scala-code.html#scala_to_java):

> You can decompile your Scala code to Java to see how a certain piece of code is translated and implemented in Java.
>
> 1. In the Project tool window, right-click a Scala class that you want to decompile.
> 2. From the context menu, select Decompile Scala to Java.
>
> IntelliJ IDEA converts code to Java and opens the converted file in the editor.
>
> You can also open a Scala class in the editor and use its context menu for the conversion.

Comment: Is this only available in the Ultimate Edition? I am on 2018.3.1 community edition but I don't see any Decompile option.

Comment: No, it's available in Community as well. You should right click at .class file (usually under `target` folder for sbt) and press "Decompile Scala to Java".

Comment: This opens empty java generated file.